# Database creation only on first run of visual c# application

Tags: c#, mysql

Any one help me to create a database in MySQL only on the first run of my c# application. Second time when i run this application if database exists then creation of database code should be skipped.

Comment: Could you show us some code please?

Comment: I have not codded yet only wants some suggestins or help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use code first in the Entity Framework you can create your database from the classes in C# that define you tables and relationships.

Once you have your classes you just have to change or setup a connection string to your database and then run code... then the database will be created for you... by magic .. or your classes!!

There are many samples online
Code First with Azure
http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2015/04/entity-framework-code-first--mysql-azure.html

[Entity Framework Code First - Create Database with MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766466/entity-framework-code-first-create-database-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static bool CheckDatabaseExists(SqlConnection tmpConn, string databaseName)
{
    string sqlCreateDBQuery;
    bool result = false;

    try
    {
        tmpConn = new SqlConnection("server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=yes");

        sqlCreateDBQuery = string.Format("SELECT database_id FROM sys.databases WHERE Name 
        = '{0}'", databaseName);

        using (tmpConn)
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCreateDBQuery, tmpConn))
            {
                tmpConn.Open();

                object resultObj = ExecuteScalar();

                int databaseID = 0;    

                if (resultObj != null)
                {
                    int.TryParse(resultObj.ToString(), out databaseID);
                }

                tmpConn.Close();

                result = (databaseID > 0);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This will work with any database name you pass in as a parameter, and it will return a bool true = database exists, false = database does not exist (or error happened).If true mean skip the creation false mean create database..

Comment: Shows error at execute scalar